# Find texture size in PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I'm making a simple 2D game for a University class with Pygame (used just for handling events) and PyOpenGL (for the graphics). I need to find the dimensions of a texture I've loaded given its textureID, but I can't figure out how to use the PyOpenGL API for this.

I know that the function I should use is `glGetTextureLevelParameteriv`, which receives as arguments:

- the ID of the texture
- the mipmap level (0 in my case)
- the texture's parameter I want to know (for me either `GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH` or `GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT`)
- a "mistery" argument `params` which is described by the PyOpenGL docs as "*Returns the requested data.*"

My problem is with the latter argument, since in "pure" C++ OpenGL that would be a `GLint*`  pointer to a variable passed by reference and used to write the returned value. However, since I'm using python passing by reference isn't really a thing and I can't figure out what to use as a fourth argument to make the function work.

The code right now is:

```py
h = [0.0]
glGetTextureLevelParameteriv(self.texture, 0, GL_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, h) # self.texture is the texture's ID
print(h) # prints "[0.0]"
```

I'm 100% sure the texture is loaded correctly. I'd like to not store the texture's size nor to define a new internal datatype to do so.

Relevant docs:

- [PyOpenGL](https://mcfletch.github.io/pyopengl/documentation/manual/glGetTexLevelParameter.html#c-glGetTextureLevelParameteriv)
- Khronos's [OpenGL docs](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGetTexParameter.xml)